# Scrape the article with Python 3.4 and BeautifulSoup ,Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape the website:

```
https://xueqiu.com/yaodewang
```

And I want to scrape all his articles .I used BeautifulSoup and Requests like that:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://xueqiu.com/yaodewang'
header = {'user-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url,headers = header).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
artile = soup.find_all('ul',{'class':'status-list'})
print(artile)
```

The result is nothing!It's return:

```
 []
```

SO,I tyr another rules like this:

```
# art = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'allStatuses no-head'})
# art = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'status_bd'})
# art = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'status_content container active tab-pane'})
```

But,It's return some words which is not right.
I want this content like that[image]

I need your help,Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired data is not actually located inside the element with `status-list` class. If you would inspect the source, you would find an empty container instead:

```
<div class="status_bd">
    <div id="statusLists" class="allStatuses no-head"></div>
</div>
```

Instead, the statuses are located inside the `script` element which you need to locate, extract the desired object, load from JSON into a Python dictionary and extract the desired information:

```
import json
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://xueqiu.com/yaodewang'
headers = {
    'user-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36'
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

pattern = re.compile(r"SNB\.data\.statuses = ({.*?});", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

data = json.loads(pattern.search(script.text).group(1))
for item in data["statuses"]:
    print(item["description"])
```

Prints:

```
The best advice: Remember common courtesy and act toward others as you want them to act toward you.
Lighten up! It&#39;s the weekend. we&#39;re just having a little fun! Industrial Bank is expected to rise,next week...
...
点.点.点... 点到这个，学位、学历、成绩单翻译一下要50块、100块的...
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It's a right methlod!But ,I want to know,if I know the content is located by the script,how I find the Regular Expression like this:pattern = re.compile(r"SNB\.data\.statuses = ({.*?});", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

Comment: Another question:I want to get the list of the artiles,but now ,I got a string.I want to get like this  result = [str01,str02.....]

Comment: @championCh sure, just extract the script text and work with it on, say, [regex101](https://regex101.com/). As for your second question, I think you are asking about putting the results into a list: `articles = [item["description"] for item in data["statuses"]]`. Hope that helps.

Comment: You help me a lot. I learned how to scrape the js page and how to convert string to list.you are greatly appreciated

Comment: I have accepted the answer use my phone.perhaps,my phone is something wrong.Thank you

Comment: @championCh okay, not a problem, just wanted to recheck. Thanks!